# Fotorama, can I change the arrow colors + center

Tags: fotorama

I am trying to use Fotorama and noticed the arrows really blend into my white container. Is there a way to change the colors on the fotorama.png and fotorama@2x.png?

Also how can I center the (large) images?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
.fotorama, .fotorama-caption {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Make sure all the wrappers encapsulating the fotorama plugin contain

```js
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
display: block;
```